# Predictable stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Assume an increasing rightcontinuous $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ has the compensator $(A_t)_{t\geq 0}$. As **saz** pointed out, we want to assume that $A_t$ is continuous. Define the stopping time $\tau_s:=\inf\{t\geq s: A_t\geq A_s+\epsilon\}$ for a given $\epsilon>0$. I want to show, that this stopping time is predictable. This means on $\tau_s>0$, there exists a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n<\tau_s$ with $\lim \tau_n=\tau_s$.

Is $\tau_n:=\inf\{t\geq s:A_t+\frac{1}{n}\geq A_s+\epsilon\}$ a legit sequence?

Comment: The compensator $(A_t)$ does not need to be continuous, right? There is some trouble if $A$ jumps at $\tau_s$, say $A$ jumps at time $\tau_s(\omega)$ from $A_s(\omega)+\epsilon/2$ to $A_s(\omega)+\epsilon$ for some $\omega$. Then $\tau_n(\omega)= \tau_s(\omega)$ for $n$ sufficiently large which means that the relation $\tau_n < \tau_s$ does not hold true.

Comment: @saz In my setup we can assume that $A_t$ is continous. I thought the usual right-continuity wouldn't cause problems. But you pointed out that it may does. I edit it to my question. Lets assume $A_t$ is continous does it hold true?

Comment: Yes, if $(A_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is continuous, then the sequence $\tau_n$ does the job.